# Visual Studio - The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data

Tags: excel, visual-studio, windows-7, odbc, office365

I am trying to run some unit tests that are using Excel spreadsheets as the data source and I am getting the following error in Visual Studio 2017:

> Message: The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library. Error details: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The test method attributes are:

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("SiteSettings.xml")]
[DeploymentItem("TestData\\My_Test_Data.xls")]
[DeploymentItem("Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe", "Drivers")]
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files; dbq=|DataDirectory|\\My_Test_Data.xls", "MyApp$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

The same project is working fine on two other machines and after looking into this further I have found out that there is a difference in the `ODBC Data Source Administrator`, which can be opened by going to `Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)`. In the `User DSN tab`, if I select the `Excel Files` and press the `Configure` button, I am getting the following error messages one after another:

[image]

[image]

Tried to google for a way to reinstall the Excel driver, but didn't find a straightforward way.

OS: Windows 7 x64.

Office: MS Office 365 (2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current ODBC Driver for Excel data files is part of the *Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable*, for which [installers are freely downloadable from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).  (Note that you must choose between the 32-bit and 64-bit installer.  You can download both and install them on the same Windows environment.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after installing the MS Access Database Engine 2016 I still can't see the _Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xslm)_, I only see the old _Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)_ driver of version 6.x when running _C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad.exe_ and trying to add a new driver, but I do see the 15.x version driver when running _C:\Windows\System32\odbcad.exe_ and trying to add a new driver there.

Comment: Is there a way to add it to the x64 version of odbcad.exe?

Comment: The link I provided lets you get *either* the 32-bit *or* the 64-bit installer.  Apparently, you've installed the 64-bit, and still need the 32-bit.  You can install both on the same machine.  Please also read [this article](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin) about the 32-bit vs 64-bit ODBC administrator.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link to the article, it have added some clarity in what is going on and I have managed to solve my problem by installing the x64 _Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable_ and setting my Unit Test Default Processor Architecture to x64 by going to _Test_ -> _Test Settings_ -> _Default Processor Architecture_ and selecting _x64_ (had _x86_ selected prior to that) in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone facing this problem with Office 365 installation then installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable won't work. Microsoft recommends installing Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime for Office 365 Click-to-run installed products.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb